# PHP Admin Approval For User Registration

Tags: php, mysql, administration, user-accounts

I've been hunting forever for a simple php/mysql solution for a user to register an account - which sends a request to the administrator for approval before they can log in.
Is this possible to do, and if so is it straightforward?

Been looking for tutorials and previous questions and still got nowhere!
It successfully registers, but i havent been able to figure out sending a request to the admin email...

Thanks

Comment: How about adding another column to the `User` table called `IsApproved TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0`, then only display users with the value of `1` on your main app and users with the value of `0` on your admin page. `1` = true. `0` = false.

Comment: did you found solution ? if so please post full code as an answer, so that it will help for others....

Answer (score 2):

You can easily implement it by adding a column `is_approved` to your user table.

When a user registers you set this field to `false` by default.

Send the admin an email about the new registration and to approve the user just change `is_approved` to `true`.

You should check for this value when the user tries to login of course and deny access if it's false.

A good resource is the [sfGuard](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/trunk) package which has code that does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send email to the admin, PHP has the mail() function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
#given $email, $user
$mail_success = mail("admin@mysite.net","User Registration awating approval","User ".$user." has registered and is on the waiting list.\n User's email: ".$email);
if(!$mail_success) { echo "Warning: Mail delivery failed"; }
```

Note that the mail() function is not efficent at all for sending multiple emails.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a BOOLEAN column to your users table `user_approved` and set it to 0 by default.

When a new user registers, send an email to the admin asking for approval using the PHP mail function:

```
    $to = 'admin@yourwebsite.com';
    $subject = 'User needs approval';
    $message = 'The user {username} needs your approval' .
    '----------------------------------- ' . "\r\n" .
    'Accept: ' . $accept_link . "\r\n" .
    'Decline: ' . $decline_link . "\r\n";

    $_headers = 'From:admin@yourwebsite.com' . "\r\n"; // Set FROM headers
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send the email
```

The `accept_link` and `decline_link` can be generated using the **PHP hash function**

For example you could use a SHA512 hash:

```
$accept_link = "yourwebsite.com/approval.php?e=" . $email . "&h=" . hash('sha512', 'ACCEPT');

$decline_link = "yourwebsite.com/approval.php?e="  . $email . "&h=" . hash('sha512', 'DECLINE');
```

In the PHP script `approval.php` you can simply check the **get** variables and check if the admin wants to accept or decline the registration request.

```
$hash = $_GET['h'];
$email = $_GET['e'];

if($hash == hash('sha512', 'ACCEPT')){

  //ACCESS MYSQL DATABASE
  //FIND THE USER AND SET user_approved = 1
  //WHERE email = $email

}else if($hash == hash('sha512', 'DECLINE')){

  //MAIL THE USER NOTIFYING THAT THE ACCOUNT HAS NOT BEEN APPROVED

}
```